# Creating PayPal link with exact amount dynamically

Tags: php, paypal

how can I have a PayPal link with an exact amount (which can be changed dynamically from PHP code). I implemented a php code which is able to generate a PDF order summary with a link. I want to specify that link: if user clicks on that he/she gets redirected to PayPal platform with a predefined amount. I'm wondering about paypal.me/my_project/XUSD but if you have better solution please let me know. Example what I want t achieve: like on Envato Marketplace. When I purchase a product I get redirected to PayPal, I log in and I see immediatelly the matching amount what Envato wants to receive from me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Why not use Paypal's API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are server-based API solutions for this that will notify you when a payment is completed. But if you are looking for the simplest way to create a link:

1. https://www.paypal.com/buttons , Buy Now button
2. enter some description, and 22.33 as the amount
3. Do not make any changes under "Customize button", since they cannot be in link form
4. In step 2, uncheck saving the button at PayPal
5. Create the button and on viewing the code, "Remove code protection" above it
6. Switch to the e-mail tab

This will give you a link with variables that can be adjusted dynamically. For other variables, see [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

Comment: This is gold and exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why this question was closed as it's clear enough what was asked for and you delivered.